# How can we handle to save Object of size greater then 16MB in mongodb, is it a hard limit for any document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can we handle to save Object of size greater then 16MB in mongodb , is it a hard limit for any document ie can't we save any document larger then 16Mb in mongodb ?

is this limit in the library that we are using to save documents in mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

You need [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/).

> GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.

---

> is it a hard limit for any document ie can't we save any document larger then 16Mb in mongodb ?

Yes, it is a hard limit.

Comment: And GridFS only stores unstructured binary files. You won't be able to query or update them like normal documents.